# May I use the logo here (on the top bar) with citation?

Tags: discussion

I really like the logo for this website and would like to use it as a profile picture for my SE account. I will cite the picture in my bio. Is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, most probably not. To [quote @Pops](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/698/58):

> It's really cool that you want to do this, but unfortunately we can't let you use the site logo for the account. The reasoning comes down to the way current trademark rules work. I won't belabor that point since you're clearly already familiar with our trademark guidance page.

The relevant part of the [Trademark Guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) is this:

> **Do not** use our logo unless you have been granted special permission by Stack Exchange Inc.
>
> **Do not** use our name or logo in a way that might imply a false sense of partnership or endorsement with your product.

Comment: This *may* just be for off site usage, though, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I hope so as it is super cool